# CSS responsive margin top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position a `<div class="container"></div>` in the middle of the screen in such a way so that it's responsive to any screen size. The red marked area on the screenshot should always appear in the middle of the screen.

How to position it? Currently I'm using `margin-top:85px` when I squeeze the browser, the distance between the red marked area and the navbar should decrease as well.

[image]

Comment: when you say in the middle of the screen, your container should be in the middle horizontally ?

Comment: nope.. it should appear in the middle only for the md and lg screen size. for the xs and sm devices the input fields and the login button goes under the texts@arkantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried absolute centering? You would need to add a position relative to the parent container... You would also need to declare a height on the container element...

```
.parent-container {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

Working code snippet has been added. This code will centre your div both horizontally and vertically for any screen size.

Set the css property `position:relative` for parent of the container.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  /*it can be fixed too*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*this to solve "the content will not be cut when the window is smaller than the content": */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define some width on your container and set margin top & bottom to some desired value and left & right values to `auto` so that it will always split the remaining space on the both sides equally.

```
.container{
  width : 84%
  margin : 2rem auto;
}
```

Comment: thats only centering it horizontaly, also only if the parentelement is configuered correctly, please improve your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example

```
.container {
   width: 75%;
   margin: 50px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your container class

```
.container{
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    width:auto; 
    height:200px; /****set height****/
    margin:auto;
}
```

It will work